# How can I pass build output to next step on codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS codepipeline for CI/CD. There are two build steps on the pipeline, `Step1` and `Step2`, each of them link to a codebuild project. In `Step1`, it generates an output json file like:

```
{
  endpoint: "https://xxx",
  key: "xxx"
}
```

I'd like to pass this file to `Step2` as input parameters. How can I do that? And how can I let `Step2` uses the values in this json file, e.g.: `endpoint`, `key`.

Comment: so you have 2 build stages? not like install, post_install in the same build stage, right?

Comment: right, I have two build stages. They are

Comment: then you can simply add the file into the artifact of the first build. In the second build that artifact would be the source artifact and from that you can get the file you want. You can specify the artifact in the buildspec file of that stage.